# Loading an ApplicationContext File from AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, config

I have an application using Java config in Spring MVC. I have a WebAppInitializer and on Startup method I am using AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to load the rootContext.

From the Startup method of WebAppInitializer, how do I load a Client Jar that has applicationContext.xml file. Basically I am looking at something like this.

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.register(MyAppContext.class);
```

Looking at something Like this.

```
rootContext.register(applicationContext.xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` is to have an `ApplicationContext` configured through annotations. So there is no direct method for parsing and importing XML configurations.

What you can do is define a `@Configuration` type that imports an XML resource

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:application.xml")
class XmlConfig {}
```

and register that

```
rootContext.register(XmlConfig.class);
```